# csEnd(code): code > CS_MAX_CODE?; 143373032 999 Program exited with code 0377

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ns2

When I run LEACH on NS2, I get this error

```
csEnd(code): code > CS_MAX_CODE?; 143373032 999

Program exited with code 0377.
```

I know there are some problems in the program but I don't know how to find them. I even tried to run the program in gdb, but `where` command gives me `No Stack Trace`

Please tell me how to debug and know the specific reason of the problem?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on functions like `exit`, `assert`, `abort`.  Once you see the "Program exited" message, it's too late to get a stack trace.

Comment: I am running this on NS2. I think I cannot add break points ? or may be dont know how to add break points.

Comment: In gdb, you can add breakpoints.  Like `b exit`

Comment: no one in the world have receive this error. that is so strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so figured it out

I was getting above message due below code in LEACH

```
inline double csEnd(int code)
{
   if (code > CS_MAX_CODE || code < 0)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "csEnd(code): code > CS_MAX_CODE?; %d %d\n", code, CS_MAX_CODE);
     exit(-1);
   }
   return cs_end_[code];
}
```

this was happening because I was setting garbage code

```
  int code;
  // some other code
  setCode(code);
```